# Проверка комментариев в админке Django

Tags: django, комментарии, админка

Возникла задача: реализовать проверку комментариев пользователя в админке.

У меня есть идея сделать следующим образом: добавить в таблицу поле булевского типа, а в админке отображать как две таблицы (с комментариями, которые уже проверены и добавлены на сайт (таблица 1), и с комментариями, которые еще не проверили и на сайте их еще нет (таблица 2)).

Но я не знаю, можно ли так делать. Если можно - подскажите как это реализовать. Или какой-либо другой способ, который знаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен [ModelAdmin.list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter).

Comment: Он реализуется в admin.py?

Comment: Он в admin.py просто указывается. Одна строчка и ничего больше делать не надо.

Comment: А где его тогда реализовать? Не пойму

Comment: Нигде ничего реализовывать не надо, всё уже сделано за вас в коде Django. Просто в admin.py надо добавить одну строчку. Перейдите по ссылке, там всё очень просто написано, даже с картинками.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо